# Emacs: run shell command with regex and Lisp function to start gud

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am tring to write some Emacs Lisp function to be able to simply compile and debug Java classes within Spacemacs using its Java layer (don't want to go into complex packages like `jdee`). The compile function is defined beblow and works as expected

```
(defun my-java-compile (command)
  (interactive (list (read-string
                      "Command: "
                      (concat
                           "javac"
                       " -d "
                       java-dest-path
                       " -cp "
                       java-class-path
                       " "
                       (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))))
  (unless (file-exists-p java-dest-path)
    (make-directory java-dest-path))
  (compilation-start command nil)
  )
```

The `java-dest-path` and `java-class-path` are local variables set in the `.dir-locals.el` in the root directory of the project.

The debug function is defined as:

```
;; get fully qualified class name
(defun get-fqcn ()
  (setq get-package-name-command
        (concat
         "gsed -n 's/^package\s\+\([^;\s]\+\);\s*$/\1/p' "
         buffer-file-name))
  (setq fqpn (shell-command-to-string get-package-name-command))
  (if (equal "" fqpn) (file-name-base buffer-file-name)
    (concat fqpn "." (file-name-base buffer-file-name)))
  )

(defun my-jdb (command)
  (interactive (list (read-string
            "Command: "
            (concat
              "jdb"
              " -classpath "
              java-class-path
              " "
              (get-fqcn)))))
  (helm-M-x nil jdb command)
  )
```

I am still trying to make it work. Here are the two issues:

1. when running `shell-command-to-string` function, the `gsed -n
   's/^package\s\+\([^;\s]\+\);\s*$/\1/p' java_file` command returns an empty
   string `""`, while it returns the fully qualified package name as
   expected when running in a terminal. If I change it to `gsed -n '/^package/p'`, the emacs function return the package line OK. So
   it seems `shell-command-to-string`  could not handle the regular
   expression in `gsed`. Any work around?
2. I could not find the function to trigger the `gud` or `jdb` . What would be the `gud` equivalent of `compilation-start` function?

Comment: The working directory of your `shell-command-to-string` is probably different than the one you have at the prompt.  Maybe specify a full poath to `java_file`, or make sure you run it in the correct directory.

Comment: @ tripleee `buffer-file-name` contains the full path of the file. As I mentioned if `gsed` with non-regex, it returns the whole import line, so path is unlikely the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The problem is that you want to include backslashes in your regexp, but backslashes are already used as escape characters in Emacs Lisp strings.  Let's try displaying the string in the echo area:

   ```
   (message "%s" "gsed -n 's/^package\s\+\([^;\s]\+\);\s*$/\1/p' ")
   ```

   This displays:

   ```
   gsed -n 's/^package +([^; ]+); *$/^A/p'
   ```

   So as you can see, the backslashes were "eaten" by the Emacs Lisp parser.  We need to double the backslashes in order for them to appear literally in the string we send to `gsed`:

   ```
   "gsed -n 's/^package\\s\\+\\([^;\\s]\\+\\);\\s*$/\\1/p' "
   ```

   Alternatively, implement the search in Emacs Lisp:

   ```
   (save-excursion
     (goto-char (point-min))
     (search-forward-regexp "^package[[:blank:]]+\\([^;[:blank:]]+\\);")
     (match-string 1))
   ```
2. The function for running jdb inside gud is `jdb`:

   ```
   (jdb command)
   ```

Comment: Thanks much for the tips. It is kind of tricky. Emacs' own regex use backslashes but it "eat" the backslashes when passed as shell command. The shell command returns the string correct but with a new-line at the end, has to remove it with `(setq fqpn (replace-regexp-in-string "\n\\'" "" fqpn))`

Comment: Also Emacs sometimes complains that Symbol’s value as variable is void: jdb when call `my-jdb` with a fresh session, but not always. I added `(require 'gud)` and the problem seems go away. But I don't see why it is needed as  `M-x gdb` or `M-x jdb` works all the time

Comment: Use `shell-quote-argument`, then your code doesn't need to have the backslash horror.  You should probably always use `shell-quote-argument` before sending something to the shell.  Note that it will also quote the spaces, so it's for a list of arguments, not an entire shell command.

Comment: Looks like `shell-quote-argument` is not for this purpose. `(shell-quote-argument "gsed -n 's/^package\s\+\\([^;\s]\+\\);\s*$/\1/p' ")` returns `"gsed\\ -n\\ \\'s/\\^package\\ \\+\\\\\\(\\[\\^\\;\\ \\]\\+\\\\\\)\\;\\ \\*\\$/\\/p\\'\\ "`, and the result was wrong as one can expect.

Comment: Yes, `shell-quote-argument` won't save you from backslashes in this case. What might be worth doing is `(concat "gsed -n 's/.../../' " (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))`. That ensures that the command works even if the file name / path contains spaces or special shell characters.